# how to align 'Actions' column in material table react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

i want to align actions column left side in the table,  this actions column is given default in table configuration, please help me to apply style for that actions column

Comment: Can you show more detail about your problem? You can upload your code to codesandbox.

Comment: yes i will send u image